# Disabling AppNap for Terminal

Tags: macos, power-management, terminal.app, osx-mavericks

How do I disable AppNap for Terminal? Get Info on Terminal does not have `Prevent App Nap` check box

[image: Terminal Info]

An alternative is to turn the `NSAppSleepDisabled` flag on, but will it actually work?

`$ defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES`

---

#### Why Disable App Nap for Terminal

I frequently have long running jobs on Terminal, such as debugging a server, downloading large files or backing up large amount of files. There is a risk of interrupting a network session when (if?) App Nap is enabled for Terminal.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, the Terminal command that you provided does prevent App Nap**:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES
```

---

I tested the command, and it worked successfully…

- #### Before:

  [image]
- #### After:

  [image]

Comment: FYI: I was testing this in OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) and the key is now **L**SApp**Nap**IsDisabled and not `NSAppSleepIsDisabled`.  (The bold characters have changed.)

Comment: when you disable app nap for terminal, does this mean it is disabled for all processes that are started from the terminal as well?